# Create Column with Lap Times Given Total Time Elapsed

Tags: sql, pandas, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have four different people, each run laps and I need to calculate lap time for each lap for each person. I am given the total elapsed time starting from the very beginning at the end of each lap. What kind of PySpark/SQL/Pandas syntax could I use to calculate lap times efficiently?

Example:

Each row represents one person running one lap.

| PersonID | Total Time Elapsed (sec) | **Lap Time** (sec) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 200 |
| 1 | 300 | 100 |
| 1 | 550 | 250 |
| 2 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 150 | 50 |
| 2 | 250 | 100 |
| 3 | 150 | 150 |
| 3 | 500 | 350 |
| 4 | 100 | 100 |
| 4 | 300 | 200 |
| 4 | 350 | 50 |
| 4 | 460 | 110 |

I need to create the 3rd column, Lap Time, using only the first two columns. I could write a for loop that would eventually work but what is the best/efficient PySpark/SQL/Pandas way to get there?

Comment: quicker would be using window function LAG in spark directly https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window functions could do it.

- PySpark:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(1, 200), (1, 300), (1, 550), (2, 100), (2, 150), (2, 250),
       (3, 150), (3, 500), (4, 100), (4, 300), (4, 350), (4, 460)],
      ['PersonID', 'Total_Time_Elapsed'])

  w = W.partitionBy('PersonID').orderBy('Total_Time_Elapsed')
  df = df.withColumn(
      'Lap_Time',
      F.coalesce(
          F.col('Total_Time_Elapsed') - F.lag('Total_Time_Elapsed').over(w),
          'Total_Time_Elapsed'))
  df.show()
  # +--------+------------------+--------+
  # |PersonID|Total_Time_Elapsed|Lap_Time|
  # +--------+------------------+--------+
  # |       1|               200|     200|
  # |       1|               300|     100|
  # |       1|               550|     250|
  # |       2|               100|     100|
  # |       2|               150|      50|
  # |       2|               250|     100|
  # |       3|               150|     150|
  # |       3|               500|     350|
  # |       4|               100|     100|
  # |       4|               300|     200|
  # |       4|               350|      50|
  # |       4|               460|     110|
  # +--------+------------------+--------+
  ```
- SQL:

  ```sql
  SELECT
      PersonID,
      Total_Time_Elapsed,
      COALESCE(
          Total_Time_Elapsed - LAG(Total_Time_Elapsed) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Total_Time_Elapsed),
          Total_Time_Elapsed) Lap_Time
  FROM df
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pandas solution, one of the approaches could be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data=[[1,200],[1,300],[1,550],[2,100],[2,150],[2,250],[3,150],[3,500],[4,100],[4,300],[4,350],[4,460]]
df = pd.DataFrame(
data,columns=['PersonID','Total Time Elapsed (sec)']
)
print(df.head(50))
# Peform groupby on PersonID
grouped_df=df.groupby(by='PersonID')
series_list=[]

for name,grp in grouped_df:
  result=grp['Total Time Elapsed (sec)'].diff() # Compute difference between current and prev row
  result=result.fillna(grp['Total Time Elapsed (sec)']) # Fill na with same value in Elapsed col(same row).
  series_list.extend(result.values)

df['Lap Time (sec)']=series_list
df['Lap Time (sec)']=df['Lap Time (sec)'].astype(int) # Changing the datatype
print(df.head(50))
```